# Securing my website hosting server

Tags: web-services, .htaccess

I am hosting my website on a linux server with php5 (no mySQL). Now I am the administrator, and I'm building my first website. I want to know about security, how do I secure my site from malicious injections and hackers? With the htaccess file? And what do I need to put in there?

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no SQL, you don't have to worry about injection attacks.

Security for your site depends on what you have running on your site.  If it's only PHP, I suggest keeping important code which may reveal things such as passwords and authentication keys or functions in a separate php file outside of your wwwroot and include them.

Example:

Your website runs in /home/wwwroot/

Put your php files with important data or functions in /home/privatephp/

Now in all your php files where you want to use those private functions or call on data that you want hidden, you simply use
`include (../privatephp/privatestuff.php);` at the top of each php file.

Your privatestuff.php file can contain such things as

`$adminusername="imtheadmin";` or `$adminpassword="adminpassword";`

Then you can simply reference those variables in any PHP file where you have used the include command.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you. What if I use only HTML? Any security needed there? No passwords...I just don't want any attackers adding code to my files such as ads etc...I had a plugin on my PC that put iframe ads into my code...but this is a different scenario, since the attack was from the inside

Comment: IF you're only using HTML, just ensure your passwords to access your control panel as well as any FTP and SSH access are lengthy and difficult to guess.  Use UPPER and lower case letters mixed with numbers and special characters (%&#*@()!).  Try to not use common words, and substitute characters with numbers.  Example: hello > H31lo!

Comment: Usernames are just as important to make difficult.  If possible, don't use "Admin" or "Administrator" or anything else easy to guess.  You don't have to make it cryptic although it wouldn't hurt if you did.  In the past, I've created over a dozen usernames for certain access, some of them being called "Admin" and "Administrator", but only one of them was the real admin account, the "Admin" and "Administrator" and all the others were fakes with no rights to do anything.  They were just to waste a hacker's time :)

Comment: ok cool. thanks for the help...one last thing, any way/tool (like for instance this website: ' http://maestro-sec.com/blogs/2008/10/top-15-sql-injection-scanner/ ' to check for security vulnerabilities in my website/server/code?

Comment: Well, you can check this : [http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/) to validate your HTML, but as for vulnerabilities and security, I'm not aware of anything free, you'll have to google that one yourself I'm afraid, sorry.  But like I said before, if it's just HTML, you have much less to worry about.  Just keep your passwords complex and secure.  Good luck!